# Custom button or link in lightning tree

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, salesforce1-app, lightning-design-system

I want to add plus(+) and minus(-) button/sign at every level of lightning tree to add or delete item at particular level, is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lightning:tree` does not support that type of feature. You would want to use a [`lightning:treeGrid`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:treeGrid) instead, which allows you to do things like specifying an action column where you could add the menu items. The `onrowaction` handler is used to perform the necessary logic. I'm not going to write a full solution, which would take a significant amount of code, but it should be pretty clear if you check out the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

This will help you get a button working in the grid data in the rowAction column.  The button type will also cause the onrowaction event, so you can add a button column to do that too.  Use the buttons name and row provided in the event data to take the appropriate action.

```
       <lightning-tree-grid
                columns={gridColumns}
                data={gridData}
                key-field="name"
                onrowaction={onrowaction}
            ></lightning-tree-grid>
```

and in your javascript file:
in the grid data, define your rowActions as a column definition:

```
 get gridColumns() {
        return [
        {
                type: 'text',
                fieldName: 'id',
                label: '',
            },
                {
                type: 'action',
                fieldName: 'actions',
                label: 'Actions',
                typeAttributes: {
                    rowActions: [
                        {label: "Action A", name: 'actionNameA'},
                        {label: "Action B", name: 'actionNameB'},
                    ]
                }
            },
        ];
    }
```

And the on row action event handler

```
 onrowaction(event) {
        const actionName = event.detail.action.name;
        const clickedRowColumnContext = event.detail.row.fieldName;
        switch (actionName) {
            case 'actionNameA':
                break;
            case 'actionNameB':
        //etc.
```

More documentation at: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tree-grid/documentation

This example also helped me bridge the gap as well as the comment above linking the onrowaction event with the column rowAction. https://rajvakati.com/2018/11/13/lightningtreegrid-row-level-actions/